# Handling an invalid XML attribute in an Excel document

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to read an Excel document. For reasons that I don't understand at all, two of the cell-style names have a ctrl-d in them in xl/styles.xml in the ZIP archive storing the spreadsheet:

```
<cellStyle name="^D" xfId="20" builtinId="53" customBuiltin="true"/>
<cellStyle name="^D 2" xfId="21" builtinId="53" customBuiltin="true"/>
```

(That's a ctrl-D in both names.) Openpyxl's `load_workbook` function quite reasonably chokes with the following error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: invalid character in attribute value, line 2, column 11879
```

Approaches that I've considered:

- Preprocess and replace styles.xml
- Ignore styles altogether somehow
- Manually remove the cell styles in oocalc (or Excel)

Any ideas/advice?

Answer (score 0):

Shoot whoever or whatever produced the file because this is invalid XML! ;-) Submit a bug upstream.

If you can clean it up in MS Excel then that's going to be eaiser otherwise you can write your own preprocessor using openpyxl's code: `styles/stylesheet.py` will let you read the source without having to worry about namespaces but otherwise you should be able to change the elements inplace. Stylesheets are **almost** never that big (some libraries do produce some massive ones with junk in them).

Comment: I'd considered that solution, but it's a vendor who supplies the spreadsheet to my client, and I can't really ask the client to do manual clean up of the vendor's spreadsheet. I may end up doing a preprocessor. Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Well, whatever library the vendor is using is causing the problem. You might be able to see this in the document properties.